# geolocation error: user denied geolocation android

Tags: javascript, android, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to get a map in a fragment through a webview, using the leaflet and mapbox APIs.  When I load the fragment, the HTML element loads, but it gives me the error "Geolocation Error: User denied geolocation", and then it shows me a map, but every tile is a map of the whole world.  Can you help me spot where I'm going wrong?  I'd really appreciate it.

**map.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet mobile example</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/leaflet.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet.ie.css" /><![endif]-->

    <script src="file:///android_asset/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
        var map = L.map('map');

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/0/0/0.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGF4Ymx1ZXJpYmJvbiIsImEiOiJjaWpsdzV0cTUwMDVkdGhtNWpoYThwaDFmIn0.WlqGs3T0nqsgy9HBPDpWWw', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);

        map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

        function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

        map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

        function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**fragment1.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebViewFragment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import me.paxana.alerta.R;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private WebView mWebView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        mWebView= (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/map.html");
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you requested location permission in the app's manifest?

Answer (score 0):

try putting these permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and see if it fixes it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```